# Swift how to move sprite?

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to know how to move a sprite in spritekit depending on the side of the screen the user is pressing down on. Like if the user taps the right side of the screen the sprite should move to the right and when the user removes his finger the sprites stops moving. 
Any suggestions?
thank you so much

Comment: I'll give you a downvote.  1. Lack of crucial tags  2. You don't show what you have done so far.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information as I’m playing around with the platform and couldn’t find any questions relating to this question. This is my first time posting a question. I will provide more information in future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the touchesBegan func and get position of touch with:

```
for location: AnyObject in touches {
var positionOfTouch = location.locationInNode(self)
//position of touch is of value CGPoint
}
```

store the value of xposition and yposition

```
var xPostion = positionOfTouch.position.x
var yPosition = positionOfTouch.position.y
//all in the touchesBegan func
```

make an if else statement to see if the user touches a side or not

```
if xPosition < 10 && yPosition > 10 && yPosition < self.size.height-10 {
//left side
let moveToLeftSide = SKAction.moveTo(x: 0, duration: 10)
object.run(moveToLeftSide)
}
```

continue setting values for the sides, then set the touchesEnded func
inside the touchesEnded func, write:

```
object.removeAllActions()
```

hope it helped... if you found this answer helpful remember to set this answer to correct ; )